# unable to get the value of selected from dropdown in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I have this dropdown and I can't retrieve the selected value. It returns an array with no value.

Here's my view:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/test'); ?>


        <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_label("Select Restaurant:",'class="form-control"'); ?>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                 <?php
                    echo '<select id="resto_list" name="resto_list">';
                        echo '<option value="">--Choose Option--</option>';
                        foreach($dropdvals as $value){
                            echo '<option value="' . $value->id . '">' . $value->resto_name . '</option>';
                        }

                    echo '</select>';
                    echo '</td>';
                    ?>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_submit('Go','Go','class="btn btn-danger"');?>
                </div>
            </td><!-- 
        </tr>
    </table> -->
```

my controller:

```
public function test()
{
    if($this->input->post('Go') != false )
    {
        $selected['resto_name'] = $this->input->post('resto_list');
        var_dump($selected);
    }
}
```

tried using var_dump to see the value but this is the result:

> array(1) { ["resto_name"]=> string(0) "" }

Here's my model of how I populated the dropdown

```
public function randc_dropdown()
{

    $this->db->select('resto_id')
            ->select('resto_name')
            ->select('count(*)')
            ->group_by(array('resto_id', 'resto_name'))
            ->having('count(*) >= 1');

    $query = $this->db->get('rates_comments');
    return $query->result();


}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Did you solve this yet?

Comment: No not yet. @Mr.Concolato

Comment: Have you tried echoing your query and running it in a GUI DBMS tool?

Comment: Hi, I've solved this problem already!! I just replaced the value that I passed from the view with $resto_id instead of $resto_name. Thank you @Mr.Concolato for the help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing resto_name from my view, I passed the resto_id. It's easier to fetch and compare data when you're using the id. Thanks for the help!!